# Infinitesimals meaning in this context

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science, calculus

I was solving this rocket propulsion's classic mechanics exercise: M is the instantaneous rocket's mass, and v its velocity. The exhaust gases are ejected with speed  relative to the speed  of the rocket (there's the weight and friction forces acting on the rocket, but that's not relevant for now). So with $\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt} = \sum{}\vec{F}_{ext}$ in mind, I went for $$d\vec{p} = M(t+dt)\vec{v}(t+dt)+[(M(t)-M(t+dt))(\vec{v}(t+dt)+\vec{u})]-M(t)\vec{v}(t) \qquad \textbf{(1)}$$ what lead me to $$d\vec{p} = M(t)\vec{v}(dt)-M(dt)\vec{u} \qquad \textbf{(2)}$$
I don't have sure if the expression "t+dt" in (1) is acceptable or makes sense. I think it does, I'm adding an infinitesimal quantity of time since I'm taking an infinitesimal change of the momentum. But my main doubt is about the "M(dt)" and the "$\vec{v}$(dt)" in (2). **Does M(dt) stands for dM?** M(dt) is an infinitesimal change in rocket's mass, but that change could be different depending on the point we're taking into consideration, i.e., if M(t) has different slopes through time, changing different starting points will also change this dM, right? Am I interpreting this correctly? I have some uncertainties when dealing with infinitesimals, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $M(dt)$ or $v(dt)$ is not acceptable. Typical notations are like:

At the time $t$:

- mass of rocket  $M(t)$
- velocity of rocket $\vec{v}(t)$

Then at the time $t+dt$

- mass of rocket $M(t+dt) = M(t) + dM$
- velocity of rocket $\vec{v}(t+dt) = \vec{v}(t) + d\vec{v}$
- mass ejected $ dm = -dM = M(t) - M(t+dt) $ ( Note that $d M$ is negative.)
- eject velocity w.r.t ground $\vec{v}(t) + \vec{u}(t) + d\vec{v}$

Therfore, the momentum change from $t$ to $t+dt$

$$
   d\vec{p} = \vec{p}(t+dt) - \vec{p}(t) = \{ (M(t)+dM) (\vec{v}(t) + d\vec{v}) - (\vec{u}(t) + \vec{v}(t) + d\vec{v}) dM\} -\{ M(t) \vec{v}(t) \}
$$
$$
   d\vec{p} = M(t) d\vec{v} - \vec{u} dM
$$

Where $dM = M(t+dt) - M(t) \lt 0$ and $d\vec{v} = \vec{v}(t+dt) - \vec{v}(t)$. Also note that $\vec{u}$ is in the opposite direction of $\vec{v}$. In the scalar expression, giving $v$ positive, $u$ should be negative.

Comment: M(dt) didn't sound right, to be honest. There are some things in your reasoning that I would like to check if you don't mind tho. 1) Why is M(t)+ dM the rocket's mass after t+ dt? The rocket is losing fuel, shouldn't it be M(t) - dM? 2) I get that dm = -dM; what I don't get is -dM = M(t) -M(t+dt)- since M(t) > M(t+dt), M(t)-M(t+dt) should be positive? And finally, if we're at t+dt, why is the eject velocity v(t)-u and not v(t+dt)+u? (you are adding vectors)

Comment: @arpg $ dM = M(t+dt) - M(t) $ this is define in the usualy calculus way, in order to perform integral later. and thus defined $dM$ is negative. therefore $-dM$ is positive as $dm$. Such definition of $dM$ is to have integral in the time fowardly..

Comment: @arpg The velocity of enjected gas in the gound coordinate should be $\vec{u} + \vec{v} + d\vec{v}$ at time $t+dt$. With undersatnding that $\vec{u}$ is in the opposite direction of $\vec{v}$. And the $d\vec{v}$ together with $dM$ will be neglected as the 2nd order of infinitesimal. I will edit the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$d M$ would be equal to $M(t+dt) - M(t)$, as an infinitesimal $M$ is the change in $M$ after an infinitesimal time $dt$.

Comment: Yes, but am I allowed to do the following: dM = M(t+dt) - M(t) = M(dt)?

Comment: As you don't know the function M(t), to do so would be an assumption. It doesn't hold generally.